# How to apply two 'if; in a def in python

Tags: python

```
input=('befelled','recalled','expelled','swelled','tested','marked','scott','brutt')
```

I want an output which looks like,

```
output=('befel','recal','expel','swel','test','mark','scott','brutt')
```

It's like if the word ends with 'ed', remove the 'ed' else return to the similar word, the second condition would be if the word ends with 'll' after applying the first condition then remove the 'l' and return the output

I want to apply two ifs

First if will check for all the words which end with 'ed' and then this if will remove the last two alphabets from the words which satisfy the first if.

Then I want to aplly the second if which will look for all the word s which end with 'll'

```
words=('befelled','recalled','expelled','swelled','tested','marked','scott','brutt') . 
def firstif(words):  
    for w in words:  
        if w.endswith('ed'):  
             return (w[:-2]) . 
        else:  
            return(w) . 
firstif(w) . 
words2=tuple(firstif(w)) . 
def secondif(words2):  
    for w2 in words2:  
        if w2.endswith('ll'):  
            return (w2[:-1]) . 
        else:  
            return(w2) . 
secondif(w2)
```

This code is running but giving me weird output

Comment: Well, for one, you are calling `firstif()` with `w`, not `words`, so this won't work. Secondly, you're calling `firstif()` twice, the second time taking its output and casting it to be a tuple. Thirdly, you're returning `w`, which is the first word in `words`, it will never get to the next word in `words`. Same problem applies to the second function.

Comment: The variables inside the `def` are not available outside. This is a common beginner FAQ. Your current code will simply throw an error when you attempt to use the undefined variables.

Comment: What about for words like beed, steed, incorporated... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative way by using **map()**

**Note:** I don't recommend you to use **input** as a variable name since there's a function called **input()** as well.

```
def check(word):
    temp_word = word[:-2] if word.endswith('ed') else word
    return temp_word[:-1] if temp_word.endswith('ll') else temp_word

user_input=('befelled','recalled','expelled','swelled','tested','marked','scott','brutt')

res = tuple(map(check, user_input))
```

Result:

```
res
('befel', 'recal', 'expel', 'swel', 'test', 'mark', 'scott', 'brutt')
```

Comment: Is it important to make it tuple, if I do not overtly make it tuple then what will be the type of the output which we get automatically?

Comment: @Apurva It doesn't have to be tuple(), you can use list() or set() as well. Using map() will return a map object; therefore, it's necessary to convert it to sequence objects (tuple, list, set, etc.).

Comment: A very helpful suggestion, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested loops to check would be a better idea. Just try:

```
words=('befelled','recalled','expelled','swelled','tested','marked','scott','brutt') . 
def fix_word(words):
    temp = []
    for w in words:
        if w.endswith('ed'):
            if w.endswith('lled'):
                temp.append(w[:-3])
            else:
                temp.append(w[:-2])
        else:
            temp.append(w)
    return tuple(temp)
```

Comment: The algorithm seems very nice, but there were some errors while I run this program on my machine

Answer (score 0):

I can also use `elif`

```py
words=('befelled','recalled','expelled','swelled','tested','marked','scott','brutt')
a=[]
for w in words:
    if w.endswith("lled"):
        a.append(w[:-3])    
    elif w.endswith("ed"):
        a.append(w[:-2])
    else:
        a.append(w)
```

result

```py
>>>tuple(a)
('befel', 'recal', 'expel', 'swel', 'test', 'mark', 'scott', 'brutt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it in **pythonic** way (one line)

```
words = ['befelled','recalled','expelled','swelled','tested','marked','scott','brutt']
clean_words = [(e[:-3] if e.endswith('lled') else e[:-2] if e.endswith('ed') else e ) for e in words ]
```

Comment: This is very easy, neat and helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use slicing.    
inputs=('befelled','recalled','expelled','swelled','tested','marked','scott','brutt')

    def clean_word(words):
      result = []
      for word in words:
        if word[-4:] == 'lled':
          result.append(word[:-3])
        elif word[-2:] == 'ed':
          result.append(word[:-2])
        else:
          result.append(word)
      return result

    print(clean_word(inputs))
```